# google analytics code isn't working

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following Google Analytics code installed on my website:

```
<script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'G-W4975LDMYY', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
            </script>
```

The `G-W4975LDMYY` matches this in Google Analytics:

[image]

Maybe it's supposed to be matching something else?

Comment: Did you check if the code was installed properly?

Comment: @RayPrice - seems to be - http://phpseclib.com

Answer (score 3):

If the `<script>` you posted is how you have it installed, that doesn't match the `<script>` in your screenshot that Google tells you to install.  My guess is that you are taking the `G-XXXXXXX` id out of the page from Google and pasting it into a plugin that adds the code for you.

It looks like the way you have it installed is for Universal Analytics but you signed up for Google Analytics 4.  You need to either:

- [Create a universal analytics property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537?hl=en) and get a `UA-XXXXXX` id.
- Install the tracking snippet for GA4 like Google is suggesting.
- Do both.   (GA4 doesn't have all the features of UA, so many webmasters are running both simultaneously.)